# Netbeans autocomplete with CamelCase

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

Is there possiblity to autocomplete name of functions, variables etc. (`CTRL+SPACE`) in PHP editor using CamelCase notation? I mean pressing `CTRL+SPACE` and writing `ZFET` will show me eg. classes like Zend_Form_Element_Text, Zend_Form_Element_Textarea etc.

I know that such functionality is already available in `Go to type` (`CTRL+O`) and `Go to symbol` (`CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+O`) dialog, but not really in editor. Option is switchable in preferences window.

Do you know if there is possible to autocomplete like that some how?

Comment: Never heard of camelcase notation being used in this abbreviated sense. I always thought it meant naming conventions like `getUserId()` instead of `get_user_id()`

Answer (score -6):

May be you should use Eclipse, it's better with more functionality.

Comment: General answer and doesn't address the issue at all.

Comment: -1 because the question is about NetBeans and not about what IDE to use.